# what is logical reads in sql server? how to reduce no of logical?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, logical-reads

After doing my research, on how to speed up queries executed in SQL server, the majority of resources suggesting to reduce logical reads, by using the proper where clause.
What I am really interested in is to know about the work flow in SQL server:
when a stored procedure is being called by a request from an endpoint user or external system, and some tips on do's and don'ts'.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Logical reads means records you are reading from the database. Let's take a small, stupid example:

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from orders
  where client = 1234
)
where item = 9876;
```

Here you select all orders from client 1234. Then later you only take those for item 9876. So (provided the optimizer doesn't see through this and optimizes your query internally) you select many more records in the first step than needed. Reduce logical reads (and the according large intermediate result) by applying both criteria in one step:

```
select *
from orders
where client = 1234
and item = 9876;
```

(This may also effect physical reads, but doesn't necessarily have to. For instance the first query may access 100 records and then reduce that to 10, whereas the second only reads those 10. But all 100 records may be in one disk block, so both statements read one disk block, i.e. make one physical read. It can even be zero physical reads, by the way, in case the data happens to be already in the dbms cache, i.e. in memory. This also tells us that physical reads can vary for a query, while logical reads remain the same as long as the query and the data are not altered.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the two queries result in exactly the same execution plan in because the optimizer is smart enough to push the outer condition into the derived table. So the two queries will have the same number of logical reads.

Comment: thanks..can u tell stored procedures work flow when it got request from front end with indexing concepts..

Comment: Logical reads is generally pages rather than records. Except for work tables when it is records.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, I too would be surprised if the optimizer couldn't optimize this. But it serves as a simple example.

Comment: if it means, one page contains how much records.

Comment: @Martin Smith: You are right. I over-simplified a bit.

Comment: @Nandha Kumar: You can translate above queries to stored procedures: GetClientOrders plus GetClientItemOrders, where the latter calls the former OR have just GetClientItemOrders with one query. I guess that the optimizer might not see that GetClientOrders plus GetClientItemOrders could be re-written into one sigle query. So in such cases it may be advisable not to have several procedures where one calls the other only to further reduce the result set. It would be a decision between readablity and maintainability and fastest data access then.

Comment: @Nandha Kumar: As to page size: Don't worry about such internals. The less logical reads the better it is. And generally the less records you read the less pages you read.

Comment: @NandhaKumar Pages are 8 KB in size.  There are enough records in a given page to fill 8 KB.  The precise number depends on the table definition, as a table with 400 columns will likely have much larger rows than a table with 1 column.

Answer (score 61):

From [Microsoft SQL Server Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/reading-pages?view=sql-server-ver15) (Pages and Extents Architecture -> Reading Pages) has a good definition:

> The I/O from an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine includes logical and physical reads. A logical read occurs every time the Database Engine requests a page from the buffer cache. If the page is not currently in the buffer cache, a physical read first copies the page from disk into the cache.

So, a logical read is when the query engine needs to read data.  First, it looks in memory.  If the page is already in SQL Server's memory, then it uses that.  If it can't find it in memory, then that triggers a physical read and the data page is read from disk.  A logical read without a subsequent physical read is a "cache hit," basically.

The buffer cache (also known as the buffer pool) is SQL Server's primary working memory for solving queries.  When you set the amount of memory that SQL Server will use, you're controlling the size of the available buffer cache.

However, telling you what you need to do without seeing the query or knowing what the table contains and  what the data look like and how the data are indexed and organized is basically impossible.

Large numbers of logical reads may not necessarily be bad -- or, rather, not necessarily *preventable*.  What's bad is an *inordinate* number of logical reads.  If you're returning 3 rows of data, but the query engine had to scan 200 million rows of the table to do it, that's going to be very slow and you can probably improve that by rewriting the query or adding an index.

I would start by looking at how complex the queries in your stored procedure are.  Notably, I'd look for missing indexes.  If you're running `SELECT * FROM BigTable WHERE ProductDate >= '01/01/2014'`, then I'd look to see that there was an index on `ProductDate`.  If you're running `SELECT * FROM BigTable ORDER BY ProductDate DESC`, however, then, yes, an index will still help, but you'll still need to return the entire data set so you have to read the whole table anyways.  Additionally, note that logical reads refer to *page* reads, so if the `ProductDate` in question is evenly distributed around the disk, you might need to read every page or nearly every page anyways.

Beyond that, it could be that the statistics on the table are out-of-date.  If you've added 20,000 rows to a table and SQL Server still thinks there's only 2000 there, it's going to completely throw of the query planning.

Comment: could u explain more how indexing concepts works in these logical reads and its benefits.

Comment: @NandhaKumar That's a very complicated question.  There are literally books written about it.  The short answer is that the query engine will do an index seek instead of a full table scan.

Comment: as I was obsessed with this things before. i got one point which paying attention to execution plan. indexes really affect performance specially when sql plan says (index seeking) not (index scanning). scanning is like reading them all but seeking is like caching them and find the exact ones. so less logical and faster reads @NandhaKumarR you can use WITH (Forceseek) clause